# Orphan becomes detective & investigates murder among genetically engineered humans

Tags: story-identification, genetic-engineering

The story is a novel of an orphan who becomes a detective and investigates a murder. The murder occurs among three groups of genetically enhanced humans. If I remember correctly one group dies, one group commits suicide, and the last group is where the investigation takes place. I believe its one of this group who is murdered.  This group are geniuses and the detective is seduced/fascinated by a new art form invented by this group or the group who committed suicide. I can't remember much else.

Comment: Is this a short story? A novel? A film? A TV Series?

Comment: Random guess, since I don't know what media OP is asking for: [Orphan Black](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black), Canadian TV series which also aired on BBC America. "

The series begins with Sarah Manning, a con artist by trade, witnessing the suicide of a woman, Beth Childs, who appears to be her doppelgänger. Sarah takes on Beth's identity and occupation as a police detective after Beth's death. During the first season, Sarah discovers that she is a clone, that she has many 'sister' clones spread throughout North America and Europe, and that someone is plotting to kill them and her."